# Using a virtual printer to modify a receipt in a POS printer

Tags: printing

I am trying to modify the receipt printed in a POS printer using a virtual printer and some custom libraries. However I read that (old) POS printers worked by writing directly to a serial port, and if that's the case I would need more a port listener, as opposed to a conventional windows virtual printer. Is that correct?

I am trying to build a general solution, trying to cover as many cases as possible, but I got that direct serial is somewhat an outdated practice.

Comment: Sorry this is not an answer to your question but I am intrested in a same solution for my project and wanted to know what custom libraries you are using? and wht vitual printer are you using?

Comment: this looks like a fiscal printer

Answer (score 2):

Check if the printer manufacturer has a virtual serial port emulator you can use. Most old POS software was written to send commands over a COM port. The emulator essentially listens in on that port, intercepts the commands, and translates them so a modern USB or Ethernet printer can output the print jobs.

[image]

That chart can be found here with more information: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/TechnologyCategoryDetail.aspx?id=28

Answer (score 0):

This app sends data directly to a COM port and not to a Windows queue of any sort?  What port options do you have?  If you have LPT as an option that could be remapped to a share and then captured using Redmon or similar port monitor.